# Questions regarding PLT/GOT and statically linking

Tags: binary-analysis, dynamic-linking, plt

I am looking at the assembly code of a heap-overflow challenge ([heap3](https://exploit-exercises.lains.space/protostar/heap3/) in Protostar) which uses a vulnerability of an old version of `dlmalloc` to execute the exploit. Below is the assembler dump:

```
0x08048889 <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x0804888a <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x0804888c <main+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x0804888f <main+6>:    sub    esp,0x20
0x08048892 <main+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x20
0x08048899 <main+16>:   call   0x8048ff2 <malloc>
0x0804889e <main+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x14],eax
0x080488a2 <main+25>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x20
0x080488a9 <main+32>:   call   0x8048ff2 <malloc>
0x080488ae <main+37>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x18],eax
0x080488b2 <main+41>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x20
0x080488b9 <main+48>:   call   0x8048ff2 <malloc>
0x080488be <main+53>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c],eax
0x080488c2 <main+57>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x080488c5 <main+60>:   add    eax,0x4
0x080488c8 <main+63>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080488ca <main+65>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
0x080488ce <main+69>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x14]
0x080488d2 <main+73>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080488d5 <main+76>:   call   0x8048750 <strcpy@plt>
0x080488da <main+81>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x080488dd <main+84>:   add    eax,0x8
0x080488e0 <main+87>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080488e2 <main+89>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
0x080488e6 <main+93>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
0x080488ea <main+97>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x080488ed <main+100>:  call   0x8048750 <strcpy@plt>
0x080488f2 <main+105>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x080488f5 <main+108>:  add    eax,0xc
0x080488f8 <main+111>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
0x080488fa <main+113>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
0x080488fe <main+117>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
0x08048902 <main+121>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x08048905 <main+124>:  call   0x8048750 <strcpy@plt>
0x0804890a <main+129>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x1c]
0x0804890e <main+133>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x08048911 <main+136>:  call   0x8049824 <free>
0x08048916 <main+141>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x18]
0x0804891a <main+145>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x0804891d <main+148>:  call   0x8049824 <free>
0x08048922 <main+153>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x14]
0x08048926 <main+157>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x08048929 <main+160>:  call   0x8049824 <free>
0x0804892e <main+165>:  mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x804ac27
0x08048935 <main+172>:  call   0x8048790 <puts@plt>
0x0804893a <main+177>:  leave
0x0804893b <main+178>:  ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Now looking at the assembler dump what I can understand is `malloc()` and `free()` are linked to the binary statically, while `strcpy()` and `puts()` are linked using PLT.

When I try to compile this program using it's source code, I get `malloc@plt` and `free@plt`, which when compiled on my local machine uses the wrong version of `dlmalloc`. The challenge is compiled and placed on a Debian distribution which we have to boot up in order to try this challenge but I would like to try it on my local machine. Can someone explain how I will be able to compile it so that `malloc()` and `free()` are statically linked with the binary.

Comment: Why would you rebuild the binary ? It is enough to copy it to your machine and try it if you want.

Comment: Thing is copying from the virtual machine is a big pain for me and I would like to create my own versions of this particular challenge too

Answer (score 1):

You are given only the code of the `main()` and `winner()` functions because only these ones are relevant for the exploitation. But, of course, the binary embed also the code of `malloc()` and `free()` which are taken from the original Doug Lea's `malloc()` function. If you want to reproduce the same binary with the code, you may need to add the code of the [original Doug Lea's `malloc()`](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) as well.

You can find the source code [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/pub/misc/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now this might sound like a stupid question, but could you please explain how I will be able to embed the source code into the binary. I am not quite familiar with using gcc properly

Comment: @Rev-time this is probably question for StackOverflow or SuperUser since it does not involve reverse engineering